# Javascript Date() difference between passing date and date-time

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Why do I get 2 different dates with `new Date()` when I pass a date vs. when I pass a date and time?

example:

```js
Date.parse('2015-03-14')
// 1426291200000
new Date(1426291200000)
// Fri Mar 13 2015 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)

Date.parse('2015-03-14 00:00:00')
// 1426316400000
new Date(1426291400000)
// Fri Mar 13 2015 17:03:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

Comment: `new Date(1426291400000)` does not produce the result as you have shown..

Comment: @RayonDabre You're in India.. I'm in California, USA... Do you mean the results are not the same due to different timezones?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zpzswmqr/

Comment: @RayonDabre Wow! How do I find the configuration that's causing this issue no my machine?!

Comment: You can refer provided answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but I cannot comment yet. The `string` you pass in `Date.parse()` must follow the

> <strike>ECMAScript 5 ISO-8601 format support
>   .Reference link [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)</strike>
>
> [format specified in ECMAScript 2015](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format)

According to that, you the format of Date with time must be: `'2015-03-14T00:00:00'` instead of `'2015-03-14 00:00:00'`.

And since the time of `Date.parse('2015-03-14')` is at GMT+00 but `Date.parse('2015-03-14T00:00:00')` is at your time zone so if you add timezone GMT+00 to the second two time will be equal:

```
Date.parse('2015-03-14');
Date.parse('2015-03-14T00:00:00+00:00');
//1426291200000
```

Comment: Note that [*ECMAScript 2015*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) says "*If the time zone offset is absent, the date-time is interpreted as a local time*" which is compliant with ISO 8601 and was interpreted as applying to date only formats too. However, [*TC39*](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/87) in their wisdom decided that date and time without a time zone should be local, but date only should be UTC (contrary to the standard they were attempting to support).

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I get 2 different dates with new Date() when I pass a date vs. when I pass a date and time?

Because parsing strings with the Date constructor (and *Date.parse*, they are equivalent) is largely implementation dependent and therefore strongly recommended against.

> ```
> Date.parse('2015-03-14')
> // 1426291200000
> new Date(1426291200000)
> // Fri Mar 13 2015 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
> ```

ISO 8601 format dates are treated as UTC in browsers compliant with ES5 and later (and UTC, local or invalid by earlier implementations), however not all browsers are compliant. Also, the specified behaviour is inconsistent with ISO 8601, which specifies that dates without a time zone are to be treated as local.

> ```
> Date.parse('2015-03-14 00:00:00')
> // 1426316400000
> new Date(1426291400000)
> // Fri Mar 13 2015 17:03:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)
> ```

The string '2015-03-14 00:00:00' is not compliant with ISO 8601, therefore parsing is entirely implementation dependent and may be treated as UTC, local or invalid. If made compliant with the addition of a "T":

```
"2015-03-14T00:00:00"
```

it *should* be treated as local (noting the previously mentioned caveat about non–compliant implementations).

It is very strongly recommended that you always manually parse strings. Use a library, one of the many good parsers that are around or just write your own function, 2 or 3 lines should suffice.